# circuit programming using a SPLD or CPLD as a 16 bit (addressable memory) microcontroller

Tags: programmable-logic

SPLD Reference

https://www.arrow.com/en/categories/programmable-devices/programmable-logic-devices/splds

CPLD Reference

https://www.arrow.com/en/categories/programmable-devices/programmable-logic-devices/cplds

I am trying to learn how to make a cpu, but am still far away from college. So I thought I would ask here since I got alot out of it last time. Could someone help me make a basic cpu from a CPLD, 64K-bit-SRAM, EEPROM, Basic logic gates (AND, OR, NOR, NAND), MUX, DEMUX, and a program counter, or point me in the right direction?

I know about ben-eater and that's what i'm going for but I want to make a cpu that uses programmable logic.

Comment: Hi, while your goals are wonderful, this type of question doesn't fit with the mission of stack exchange sites - these are not discussion forums or general posting sites, but restricted only to specific questions which can have lasting answers right here.  Generally speaking for this type of thing you should start by reading CPU design references and existing project notes, and preferably do a lot of simulation before you build actual hardware.  When I did this years ago I used the MIT Open Coursewear 6.004 notes - they change that site around from time to time so others may be better.

Comment: Sorry, Do you think you could point me in the right direction? I've been searching for awhile now. I just thought here would be a good place. If you know of a book or resource, that would help immensely. just saw your update.

Comment: Worry first about understanding how a CPU works before you pick the target hardware for implementation.  And again, start with a simulator as it's a lot easier to rip-out and fix wires in a text editor.  It may even be worth using an FPGA before going to your relatively discrete solution, where you'll start not only needing to wire the CPLD to everything else but need additional gear to program the EEPROM, etc.

Comment: I am fresh out of high school, and i don't have the knowledge to use something like logisim. i have it but haven't a clue how to use it. I'm starting with breadboards, is that a good idea? i have an arduino for programming.

Comment: could we message on google hangouts or something? the delay is terrible.

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum.  And no, you must not start a project like this by building hardware at all - you have to understand the functioning of the design before you build anything, and that means either writing a custom simulator or learning to use an existing one.  If you plan to do this professionally in the future, use an HDL simulator for Verilog or VHDL.  Several are available free both commercial and open source.  For a CPU I'd strongly recommend a simulator you can interact with from a custom program, like iverilog with VPI.

Comment: "Nand2tetris" is one resource that comes up a lot on this subject. For CPLD or FPGA work you will almost certainly have to learn Verilog and use Modelsim, which is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

16 bit addressable memory puts you out of CPLD (and definitely SPLD) range implementations.

You can try [this](https://github.com/cpldcpu/MCPU) as a good starting point, with an 8bit cpu with 6 bit addressing as a starting point.
Read the pdf first to understand the design.

Rather than focus on the device, you need to understand the VHDL implementation of a cpu... the size of which will drive device selection.

You might read [this](http://labs.domipheus.com/blog/tpu-series-quick-links/) by Colin Riley ....a great walk through a design for a Xilinx FPGA cpu implementation.